# Parametrization of Gamma and Negative Binomial in R

Tags: r, bayesian, gamma-distribution, negative-binomial-distribution

I have some Poisson data {${y_1,...,y_n}$} and a Gamma prior, and I wish to construct a predictive posterior distribution.

As I understand, if my Gamma hyperparameters are $\alpha$ (the prior number of occurrences) and $\beta$ (the prior number of observations), the predictive posterior is: ${y\space|\space y_1...y_n,\alpha,\beta}\space\tilde\space NegBin({\sum\limits_{i=1}^n y_i+\alpha}, \frac{1}{1+\beta+n})$

However, because of the multiple parametrizations of both Gamma and negative binomial, my attempts to actually implement this in R were so far futile.

Am I right that in the above formula $\alpha$ is `shape` and $\beta$ is `rate` in `dgamma()`? Am I right then that $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n y_i+\alpha$ is `size` in `dnbinom()`? And what is `prob` then? I thought it was $\frac{1}{1+\beta+n}$, but the resulting distribution doesn't seem to make sense.

Comment: Are you sure the posterior predictive is $NB(\sum_{i=1}^n y_i + \alpha, \frac{1}{n +\beta +1})$? I have just been watching the derivation at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iCxrimJzzDo In his notation he gets $NB(\sum_{i=1}^n y_i + \alpha, n +\beta)$
In your notation that's $NB(\sum_{i=1}^n y_i + \alpha, \frac{1}{n +\beta})$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the 'NegBinomial' distribution in the R stats package `?NegBinomial`, the parameter choice is different from the one appearing e.g. in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_binomial_distribution).
The R 'prob' parameter is $\text{prob} = 1 - p$ where $p$ is as in Wikipedia's
notation and as in your notation. So in your case, use $\text{prob} = 1 - 1 / ( 1 + \beta + n)$ for the predictive distribution. The 'size' parameter is the same in the two notations, and your interpretation of it is good.

Comment: Great, it works, thanks very much! Is this because R parametrises this via the number of successes, while Wikipedia via the number of failures?

Comment: Just to add that you probably meant `?NegBinomial`, right?

Comment: I've just realised that prob = 1-1/(1+$\beta$+n) is equivalent to mean $\mu$ = ($\alpha$+s)/($\beta$+n) [since prob=size/(size+$\mu$)], which makes perfect sense.

Comment: I fixed the wrong Rhelp reference, thank you. Using the mean is appealing indeed, and noticing that 'beta' can be compared to a number of observations can be useful in choosing an informative prior.

Comment: And in fact R's NegBinomial functions can be parametrized with `mu` rather than `prob`.